# How do I use an if statement with this script?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, url-parameters

So I wrote a script. It takes the URL parameters to determine which ads to show on the website. As shown below, you can see what's going on. Variables are stored if ?layout=layout1,2,3 are appended to the URL.

```
// Parse the URL
function getURLParameter(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
  results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

islayout = getURLParameter('layout'); 

if (islayout == "layout1") {            
  localStorage.setItem("layoutvalue", 1);
}

if (islayout == "layout2") {            
  localStorage.setItem("layoutvalue", 2);
}

if (islayout == "layout3") {            
  localStorage.setItem("layoutvalue", 3);
} 
else {
  var layoutvalue = 0; 
}
```

Further on throughout the page... I'd then have a code that would use the variables received above to determine which ad codes to execute.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("layoutvalue") == 1){  
  // Ad Code for 1st set of users
}

if (localStorage.getItem("layoutvalue") == 2){  
  // Ad Code for 2nd Set of users
}
else {
  // Ad code for all users
}
```

So that's all fine and dandy... My issue is now when I get the following format for an ad code as shown below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" id="adblockid" 
 src="https://cdn.adnetwork.com/blahblah.min.js?w=12345&"></script>
```

How can I use an if statement to control when this script get's executed? because the code for this script is not between the  but rather apart of the script tags.

Let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: More conditions and/or Events.

Comment: @phpglue what do you mean by that? sorry?

Comment: Why does your the search URL look like that? What condition do you want to have happen to run the code? I didn't test `getURLParameter()`, but the whole thing looks like a bad strategy. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Take paramters from the URL (eg. website.com/?layout=layout1) and use the url parameters to determine which ads execute on the website. The only issue I have is trying how toget the bottom script to work with the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending the script to the body?

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
//Change Source depending on your ad values
s.src = "https://cdn.adnetwork.com/blahblah.min.js?w=12345&";
$("head").append(s);
```

Comment: Can you explain? Would that code above simply be able to be entered directly into the if statement?

Comment: If I understand correctly you can achieve what you want by doing something like this:

var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";

if (localStorage.getItem("layoutvalue") == 1){  
s.src = "https://cdn.adnetwork.com/blahblah.min.js?w=layout1value";
}

if (localStorage.getItem("layoutvalue") == 2){  
s.src = "https://cdn.adnetwork.com/blahblah.min.js?w=layout2value";
}
else {
s.src = "https://cdn.adnetwork.com/blahblah.min.js?w=defaultvalue";
}
$("head").append(s);

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ricky!

That didn't work. I need the data to be appending within the opened arrow brackets not the closed ones. 

<script type="text/javascript" id="adblockid" 
 src="https://cdn.adnetwork.com/blahblah.min.js?w=12345&"></script>

Comment: One more shot. Have you tried using:
$.getScript('https://cdn.adnetwork.com/blahblah.min.js?w=12345&');
 It loads a new script into the page and runs the code inside.

Comment: Hey Ricky. Thanks. I actually tried the first script you sent and it worked when I placed the script in the body as opposed to the head. I also replaced the last line "$("head").append(s);" with 
"document.head.appendChild(script);"

Thanks alot!